# URL Escaping in R

Tags: r

I am trying to assign a URL to a variable

```
css <- " <link href="https://cloud.typography.com/2/1/css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">"
```

but I get the

```
CMS.R:49:22: unexpected symbol
```

I did search previous answers and tried escaping with \ and what not but to no avail. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do the outside quote with single quotes

```
css <- '<link href="https://cloud.typography.com/2/1/css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">'
css
#[1] "<link href=\"https://cloud.typography.com/2/1/css/fonts.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">"
```

The demo is [here](http://rextester.com/GJVQ36642)

Comment: Good answer, but note that now this means that single quotes would then need to be escaped.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I think it is the same output as yours `identical(css, css1)
#[1] TRUE`

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape double quotes:

```
css <- "<link href=\"https://cloud.typography.com/2/1/css/fonts.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">"
```

### Demo